# How to enable input onclick?

Tags: jquery, html

My input is disabled on default and I want ot enable it onclick on some reference.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="field2">
  <p><b>PayPal account email</b></p>
 <input autocomplete="on" disabled="disabled" id="user_paypal_email"
name="user[paypal_email]" size="30" type="email" value="111">
<a href="/users/edit.6" id="#edit_email">Edit</a>
  </div>
```

and tried this js:

```
$("#edit_email").click(function() {
$("#user_paypal_email").removeAttr("disabled");
 });
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone suggest solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a return false in the click handler, otherwise it's reloading the page (following the href) and you may not have noticed.

```
$("#edit_email").click(function() {
  $("#user_paypal_email").removeAttr("disabled");
  return false;
});
```

Or:

```
$("#edit_email").click(function(e) {
  $("#user_paypal_email").removeAttr("disabled");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I think the correct way to do this with jquery is to use preventDefault() [http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/]

Comment: @StefanNeubert It's your choice. return false is `preventDefault()` plus `stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Ariel, can you give example ?

Comment: stopPropagation() would prevent further jQuery events to be processed (if there are any). In most cases, you don't need it but it makes life hard, if you add some more events later.

Answer (score 4):

change your anchor tag id from `id="#edit_email"` to `id="edit_email"` you don't need to add the hash to the id